# Detect UI operation which will "hang" the application if running in service mode

Tags: user-interface, delphi, service, window, scheduled-tasks

Fellow experts!

I have faced the following dilemma: some of our tools (executables) are started as scheduled tasks, some are started as services and others as usual desktop apps with interactive *Windows* user. We are using the code sharing strategy for source management (this is not debatable for this question).

**So the solution I want to find is the following**:
Detect UI operation at run-time which leads to hanging service/background task (such as say call to *Application.ShowException*, *ShowMessage*, *MessageDialog*, *TForm.Show* etc.). And when such an action detected I want to raise the exception instead. Then the operation will fail, we will have stack trace etc. but the process will not hang up! The most problematic hang up is when some event processing is done in transaction and then in some of the code used to process event suddenly (because of error in code, design, whatever) there is UI code executed then the process hangs and the DB parts can be locked!

**What I think I need to do is**: Use *DDetours* library to intercept *WinAPI* calls to a certain routines and raise exception instead (so that the process does not hang, but just fail in some method). Also I know that the creation of forms and windows does not hang the app, but only the tries to show them to the user.

Is there some known method of handling this problem? Or maybe there is some list of *WinAPI* routine set which hangs in service mode?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not a practical solution to the problem. The practical solution is the one you already ruled out.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan should it be intercepts for like TCustomControl.Show, Winapi.Windows.ShowWindow, TApplication.ModalStarted, MessageBox, ShowMessage, MessageDlg... etc.?

Comment: Just dont show dialogs when running in service mode. I have to agree with David on this one

Comment: When you use millions of line codes and third party components you cannot always control that. If I could do that then there will be no question.

Comment: You have taken a shortcut when you decided to use code that was made for a gui in your service. Now you pay the price. I see no other way then editing your code to deal with service mode

Comment: One of those examples is beautiful FastReport. So I can't use FastReport in Service? I use it to export the data to PDF (so no visual controls). But when there is error in some cases the FastReport lib showed the message instead of exception. I am not using forms in the service...

Comment: FYI: DDetours worked flawlessly for solving this. The only thing was that I did ExitProcess when UI code was executed, because the WinAPI function cannot raise exception inside (as they could be called also from DLL and other non-VCL sources).

Comment: I intercepted the following: MessageBox,MessageBoxA,MessageBoxW,MessageBoxEx,MessageBoxExA,MessageBoxExW,MessageBoxIndirect,MessageBoxIndirectA,MessageBoxIndirectW,SetWindowPos,ShowWindow,ShowWindowAsync,FlashWindow,CreateDialog,CreateDialogA,CreateDialogW,CreateDialogIndirect,CreateDialogIndirectA,CreateDialogIndirectW,DialogBox,DialogBoxA,DialogBoxW,DialogBoxIndirect,DialogBoxIndirectA,DialogBoxIndirectW,OpenInputDesktop

Comment: @Z.B. There's no reason you can't use FastReport - you just have to do it in the correct way, using a separate controller application.

Comment: Terminating the process doesn't sound like success to me. Technical debt compounds.

Comment: My task was to detect the problem and report. I did it very well. I get the stack trace where it happens and which app did that. That's all what me or other developer will need to do further improvements. We are working with monolith applications and tons of legacy, not with "fancy" clean from zero applications where you can easily refactor or implement everything in a correct way.

Comment: My question wasn't how to refactor (I know how to do things right) or how can I change the system. My task was to detect UI operations so that later team can apply required architecture/code changes. So now in the service application I can easily avoid "hang up" due to any changes (buggy or by mistake) in any dependencies by ensuring this with the strict API "contract".

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use something like madTraceProcess to get a stack trace when then process is hung?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan never used this tool. I will try that. I made this guard now so that the services and command-line tools executed in Session 0 immediately terminate (when UI API called) and write windows event log with stack trace. This just keeps us safe from possible DB locks. It happened only once.. but it locked all users of one customer - that's why we went with solution "better fail with ExitProcess than hung and lock some resource for customer".

Comment: Sometimes it could quite complex to run external tools like madTraceProcess on a customer PC/Server. I heard a lot of positive about madExcept, still team uses Jedi. Thanks for tool suggestion, we should possibly give it a try in some case.